# Specifying zip file on data partition in Clockworkmod Recovery command

Tags: android

I'm flashing a zip from within my apps data folder through cwm using commands. However i dont know how to acsess the directory i need as i'm unfamiliar with the command any help? (The DATA bit has to be the partition

```
os.writeBytes("echo '--update_package=DATA:/data/carbon.assassin.tweaks/beats.zip' >> /cache/recovery/command\n");
```

I need to know what i should place here: DATA:/data/carbon.assassin.tweaks/beats.zip to access /data/data/carbon.assassin.tweaks/beats.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i could just use /data/data/ and didnt need the DATA: bit :)